# Show a simple message box in Pentaho

Tags: java, swing, pentaho

I am moving from SSIS to Pentaho, also new in java. What I would like to do is to show a simple message box in Pentaho using the Defined Java Class step (or another one).

First I tried with this code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MyClass 
{
    public static void main(String args[]){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Hello, this message is in a message type box." );
    System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

But I got this error:

```
Non-abstract class "Processor" must implement method "boolean org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.userdefinedjavaclass.TransformClassBase.processRow
```

I modified the code:

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

```
public boolean processRow(StepMetaInterface smi, StepDataInterface sdi) throws KettleException

    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Hello world!");
        System.exit(0);

        return true;

    }
```

I tested the class, I did not receive any error message, but I could not see the message box that I was expecting.

So, my question is, what else do I need to import, specify or modify in order to achieve what I want to do.

Regards.

Comment: System.exit() exits the entire Java VM - you definitely don't want to do that. Basically, that shuts down EVERYTHING.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pdi transformations most steps require some input. Your processRow() method is called for each row, received by your User Defined Java Class step. So, if you don't have input row - the method is not called.

You may want to place some step, producing one row before and pass the output to the java step. You may use "Detect empty stream" step - it will output exactly one row without any columns. However, your java code would still require some adjustments (not sure what exactly you need to do it in java, but it seems, like you need to create some ).

So, **the easiest option** for you would be to use "Modified Java Script Value" (it uses Rhino javascript, not java) step and call `Alert("Hello world!")` function inside. But nevertheless you would still need an input row.

**If you still want to do it java way**, you may try following code (but I am not a java developer, so I am not sure how good that code is):

```
import javax.swing.*;

public boolean processRow(StepMetaInterface smi, StepDataInterface sdi) throws KettleException
{

    Object[] r = getRow();
    if (r == null) {
        setOutputDone();
        return false;
    }

    if (first)
    {
        first = false;
        myFrame = new MyFrame();
//      myFrame.setVisible(true);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(myFrame, "Hello world");
        myFrame.dispose();
    }

    return true;
}

private MyFrame myFrame;

private class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    public MyFrame() {
        super();
//      this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

Also, please keep in mind, that kettle jobs/transformations usually are not supposed to be interactive. They may be executed on linux systems, which may have no windowing system.
So displaying such messages is usually used only for debugging and is disabled in production versions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you replay. As I said I am new in PDI, I need to explore a little bit more the rest of the steps present in Pentaho. Right now I am just trying to implement the same approach I have implemented in SSIS, but I see that Pentaho is very flexible. May I ask you something else. It is mandatory to use all the time the processRow method?. So far all the examples I have seen use it.

Comment: Looks like processRow is required for User Defined Java Class (otherwise you will get that error you have mentioned). By the way, you may insert template implementation of this method from Spoon user interface (in the left side of the edit step dialog: expand Code snippets -> Common use -> double click on Main (or drag and drop it to the code editor))